# scp does not transfer files correctly

Tags: scp

I am using `scp` to transfer some large files (> 1 GB) from my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04) to my desktop (Ubuntu 14.04). The laptop has a wireless connection to my router and the desktop has a cable connection.

Out of curiosity I decided to verify the transferred files using an md5 digest: I created the digest on the source computer, transferred it to the target computer, and used it with the `-c` option to verify the transferred files. To my surprise, more than 50% of the times I get an error:

```
md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

My question: does data corruption occur so often with `scp`? I would expect that (1) data transfer errors are rather rare, and (2) `scp` checks its data and possibly resends it in case of error. What can be the cause of these errors? My hypotheses:

1. Bad WLAN connection that frequently corrupts data during transfer.
2. Bad memory: `md5sum -c` fails even thought the data is correct because the RAM is not working properly.
3. Bad hard disk: `md5sum -c` fails because the disk contains error.
4. A combination of the above reasons.

Note that my hard disk and RAM are pretty new: I bought them 5 months ago.

Comment: Problem solved: following the indications in the accepted answer I check my desktop's memory and found out it was not working properly. I replaced the RAM and then transferred the files again: all md5 files verify correctly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scp transfers files over SSH, which does cryptographic authenticity & integrity checking. That basically rules out the bad WLAN possibility.

Bad memory is reasonably likely. Note that bad memory often *starts* bad, it's not typically from getting old. Installing and running memtest86/metest86+ will either confirm this or mostly rule it out. (For ruling it out, you want to leave the test running for a while, at least overnight). If it finds an error, you don't need to keep it running, you can stop immediately and proceed to replacing DIMMs.

The disk corrupting it is also possible. Similarly, you could have bad cabling to the disk, or a defective controller, etc.

Other possibilities are filesystem bugs (unlikely if you're using something common like ext4), malware (thankfully fairly uncommon on Linux), but this is most likely a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. The partition on which I have copied the files is formatted with a `ext4` file system. I am transferring the files to the same computer to another mounted disk, to see if the problem occurs again. After that I will run a memory test.

Comment: Actually, I have just run another test, and one file that did not check now seems to be correct. Summarizing: first check NOT OK, several subsequent checks OK. I did not change the file nor the md5 file, just ran the check several times. So this should point to bad memory.

Comment: @Giorgio It could also be the disk reading it back wrong, or a defective CPU, but I'd go with bad memory as most likely. Note that if you do have bad memory, it has been silently corrupting your data for a while...

Comment: I know. This has been going on for a few months. Luckily most of my important data is source files. I also have an old backup on disk which was done on the old computer. I might check it against my current data after I have solved this problem (provided memory turns out to be the problem).

Comment: I have now `scp`-ed from the laptop to the desktop on another disk (an external USB drive), and I have the same problem. So either both disks have the same defect, or it is something else.

Comment: @Giorgio I hope its memory (and it probably is). That's fairly cheap and easy to replace.

Comment: It is the memory: I booted a linux recovery usb and the test immediately filled the screen with error messages. Tomorrow I will go to the shop where I bought the memory, maybe they'll replace it. Otherwise I will buy new memory.

Comment: @Giorgio Best of luck. Once you've got working memory in the system, you'll want to at least verify your install (using, say, debsums) if not reinstall. I'm surprised you're not seeing random crashes and other weirdness (or, if you are, that's another problem caused by the bad memory).

Comment: Memory does get bad over time. I don't recall ever getting new bad memory (but I do know people who've had it happen). I have several times retired months- or years-old memory sticks because they'd gone bad.

Comment: @Gilles odd, I've had three sticks go bad after time, but at least two dozen defective on arrival. Depends on where the RAM comes from, of course.